# Is there an interesting model structure on sSet whose fibered objects are exactly contractible Kan Complexes?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

For the Kan-Quillen model structure, the fibered objects are exactly the Kan Complexes and for the Joyal model structure, the fibered objects are exactly the $\infty$-categories. This follows from the theorems, that a simplicial set $X$ is a Kan Complex/$\infty$-category iff $X\rightarrow\Delta^0$ is a Kan fibration/isofibration, which are the respective fibrations in the Kan-Quillen/Joyal model structure.

We also have, that a simplicial set is a contractible Kan Complex iff $X\rightarrow\Delta^0$ is a trivial Kan fibration. Is there an interesting model structure, where they are exactly the fibered objects? Of course we could just define the new (trivial) fibrations as trivial Kan fibrations and the new (trivial) cofibrations as all morphisms having the left lifting property to them, while all morphisms are the new weak equivalences, but that's just boring. Is there an interesting model structure? If yes, how is it constructed? If not, how do you prove it?

Comment: There is the model structure where the cofibrations are the monomorphisms and the weak equivalences are all maps. Then the fibrations are the trivial fibrations and the fibrant objects are the contractible Kan complexes. This model structure is the left Bousfield localization of the Kan-Quillen model structure by the inclusion of the empty space into the point. This is a particular case of the model structure for $n$-truncated spaces (killing the $(n+1)$-dimensional sphere) for $n=-2$.

Comment: Good day, Sir! What a surprise! I am currently reading "Higher Categories and Homotopical Algebra" on which Marc Nieper-Wißkirchen bases his lecture. I have heard of Bousfield localizations already, but not read about them yet. I will take a bit of time for this soon.